# React Native Foldable Devices

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm working on a project where one of the requirements we were asked was to support foldable devices, unfortunately I can't find much content on the internet about their development in React Native.

Is there a library or something that React Native has to know if the device on which the user is using the application is a foldable device?

I'm very new to the subject and would like to know if anyone has come up with strategies to solve this "problem". For example, when the foldable device is open it shows the text "Open", if it is closed it shows "Closed".

Comment: You will have to work with dimensions. Check documentation [https://reactnative.dev/docs/dimensions#example]

Comment: From what I had already tested, the width of the window would be the answer, but how would the logic be to know if the device's state, if it would be folded or unfolded? Do you have any codesnipet you can share?

Comment: you can use https://github.com/react-native-toolkit/react-native-responsive-dimensions

Answer (score -1):

```
const { width } = Dimensions.get("window")   
const [bannerWidth, setBannerWidth] = useState<number>(width)
useEffect(() => {
        const remove = Dimensions.addEventListener("change", status => {
            console.log(status.window.width)
            setBannerWidth(status.window.width)
        })
        return () => {
            remove.remove()
        }
    }, [])

console.log(bannerWidth)
```

do this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).